# Replace forbidden characters function check python

Tags: linux, python, shellcode

I have "blackbox" with the following python function code (without permission to change it):

```
def exec_ping():
    forbidden = ['&', ';', '-', '`', '||', '|']
    command = input('Enter an IP: ')
    for i in forbidden:
        if i in command:
            print('Invalid characters')
            exit()
    os.system('ping ' + command)
```

I want to execute this function with the following command input:

```
-c 1 localhost; whoami;
```

To get this command to be running:

```
ping -c 1 localhost; whoami;
```

How can I bypass the forbidden characters check? Can I use another characters/encoding?

Comment: Side note: This script (which is presumably a teaching tool) is a **great** demonstration of why whitelisting or explicit type deserialization is better than blacklist attempts - parsing out an IP address (v4 or v6) would be both easier, faster (given the nested loops), and additionally more secure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(whoami)` should bypass the filter and executes `whoami`.